# StateFlow with BufferOverflow.Suspend

Tags: android, kotlin, mobile, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow

I am creating a `Manager` class which contains its state, `InternalError`, `Running` and `Idle`. This is currently placed in a `StateFlow`. Issue I have is that I can't lose any values, meaning `onBufferOverflow=BufferOverflow.DROP_LATEST` strategy is not suitable for me. I need to change `onBufferOverflow` strategy to `BufferOverflow.SUSPEND` in order to have the behaviour I need.

Note that this is a manager class so I don't have access to the scope to be able to do something like `.stateIn(scope = scope ..... )`

I would also go with `SharedFlow` with `.distinctUntilChanged()` but again I would need to convert using `.sharedIn(scope = scope ..... )` which I don't want to have in this `Manager` class.

Comment: You probably want to use a channel and consume it as a (shared) flow. You don't want to use state flow at all because it's always conflated so it has no guarantee to emit values beside current one. And you don't want to use MutableSharedFlow either because it drops incoming values when it has no subscribers.